# Docker Desktop on Windows11: kubectl get pods gives error on my laptop: The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:49994 was refused

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I want to run Kubernetes locally so I can try it out on a small Java program I have written.

I installed WSL2 on my Windows 11 laptop, Docker Desktop, and enabled Kubernetes in Docker Settings.

There are a number of SO questions with the same error but I do not see any of them regarding Windows 11 and Docker Desktop.

I open a terminal, type `wsl` to open a linux terminal. Then I issue the command:

```
$ kubectl get pods
The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:49994 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

but I see

[image: docker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Docker Desktop and Kubernetes on Linux Ubuntu, I got the same error, but also with Docker Desktop being unable to start normally because **I already had a Docker Installation** on my machine, resulting in the **docker context** being set to the default Docker environment **instead of the required Docker Desktop**.

Confirm the following first:

1. **Make sure **[kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-windows/)** is correctly installed and ~/.kube/config file exists and is correctly configured on your machine** because it holds the configuration of the cluster info and the port to connect to, which both are used by kubectl.
2. Check the context with

   `kubectl config view`
3. If not set to current-context: docker-desktop, for example

```
   apiVersion: v1
   clusters:
   - cluster:
       certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
       server: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
     name: docker-desktop
   contexts:
   - context:
       cluster: docker-desktop
       user: docker-desktop
     name: docker-desktop
   current-context: docker-desktop
   kind: Config
   preferences: {}
   users:
   - name: docker-desktop
     user:
       client-certificate-data: REDACTED
       client-key-data: REDACTED
```

**then Set the docker context to Docker Desktop on your machine**

`kubectl config use-context docker-desktop`

If that doesn't solve your issue maybe you have to check for **specific Windows 11 Docker Desktop Kubernetes configuration/features**

Check also:
**[Docker Desktop Windows FAQs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/windowsfaqs/)**